# property and value attributes for struts logic tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Trying to understand some basic Struts here:

`<logic:equal name="myForm" property="myFlag" value="Y">`

I understand from legacy code, that there is a String variable called `myFlag` in the `myForm` Java class. However, can you pass a variable in the same manner to `value` In otherwords:

`<logic:equal name="myForm" property="myFlag" value="secretJavaValue">`

Where in the `myForm` Java class, we have:

```
String myFlag = "";
final String secretJavaValue = "iLoveC";
getMyFlag();
setMyFlag(String flag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<logic:equal name="myForm" property="myFlag" value="<%=secretJavaValue%>">
```

The *value* for the `value` atribute in the [`logic:equal`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/taglib/logic/package-summary.html#doc.Properties) is always a literal value.

Comment: so using `<%=` on the JSP page would be able to reference the string value from the `myForm` Java class?

Comment: With this way, you can compare the value of your property with _dynamic_ value (a variable).

Comment: Is there any way to retreive that value on to another jsp? (With sessions, or whatever?)@PaulVargas